# Extrude equally along faces, not normals

Tags: extrude

I'm new at Blender and struggle with platings.

I have this piece of geometry that has been stolen from main mesh.
[image: Plate]

And try to make sort of SciFi looking plane like this, but this has been done manually extruding all faces and than moving them to the sides and up.

[image: Target shape]

but if I just extrude alongside normals I get this weird result (Of course it's exaggerated extrude, just to show what is wrong)
[image: Extrude alongside normals]

It's fairly simple shape, and it's very easy to do that manually, but what if we have much more complex objects and plates? How to do plating properly? It has to look like hard surface, not organic matter.

If the example is not enough I have the exact same problem on vent.

[image: vent]

extruded alongside normals

[image]

[image]
We can clearly see that something is off

Extruded manually[image]

All faces are at 90 degrees angle, no distortions.

Also solidify modifier gets the same weird results, but I believe the only thing that solidify do is to extrude along normals.

Comment: there is a third extrude option called >extrude individual faces<.  that might not be what you want though, because it doesn't extrude corners with it.  the only other option I see is to fix your normals on your shape, which shouldn't be too hard considering they are pretty simple shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the scale, before you extrude.

In *object mode* press <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> while the desired object is selected and than click on scale.

Comment: Sadly, scale is applied.